# Fix MultipleBagFetchException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There are already lots of hints and questions on this topic.
For my specific case i have questions on modelling/fetching data with spring-data-jpa and hibernate.

Here is my domain model:
`Focus` -->  1:N --> `Module` --> 1:N  --> `Course`

So one `Focus` consists of one or more `Module` which itself consists of one or more `Course`.
I want to fetch a certain `Focus` with a given ID of let´s say 1:

So my jpql would be:
`select f from Focus f inner join fetch f.modules m inner join fetch m.courses c where f.id = :id`

By using `List` on the to-many mapping i got the above `MultipleBagFetchException`. By using `Set` it disappears and the `Focus` gets materialized the right way (with modules and courses).

My questions:

- Is the performance impact such a deal when using `Set`? I have the id constraint which limits the focus on just one?
- The suggested solution to `MultipleBagFetchException` given here https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/ says

> To avoid a Cartesian Product, you can fetch at most one association at a time. So, instead of executing a single JPQL query that fetches two associations, we can execute two JPQL queries instead:

So how should i formulate two queries being materialized as one `Focus`?
The first query is easy:
`select f from Focus f inner join fetch f.modules where f.id = :id`

But how to fetch the `Course`? Owner of the `Course` is `Module` not `Focus`?
`select f from Focus f inner join fetch f.modules ???`
`select m from Focus f inner join f.modules m inner join fetch m.courses ???`

Speaking of performace:
I can do two or even three queries (fetching all separately - 1. fetch focus, 2. fetch associated modules 3. fetch associated module`s courses) - that is not a problem.

But afterwards (for my understanding) i have to take care how the `Focus` is materialized, because in the above case i have one `Focus` a list of `Module` and a list of `Course`. So in that case hibernate cannot materialize a `Focus` with all members.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the performance impact such a deal when using `Set`?

This one is difficult to answer in general. I would say it depends on number of records in all tables. You could go with such solution and see how it scales.

> So how should I formulate two queries being materialized as one `Focus`?

For this one, I could suggest you an implementation I've used in one of my projects, but you might find another. It's similar to approach Vlad Mihalcea explained, but adapted to Spring Data JPA.

You would extend `FocusRepository` with your custom implementation:

```java
public interface FocusRepository 
        extends JpaRepository<FocusEntity, Integer>, 
                FocusRepositoryCustom 
{
    // other methods
}

public interface FocusRepositoryCustom {

    FocusEntity findByIdFetchModuleFetchCourse(int id);

    // other methods
}
```

For the implementation of a custom repository, you could use Criteria API.

```java
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class FocusRepositoryCustomImpl implements FocusRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public FocusEntity findByIdFetchModuleFetchCourse(int id) {
        // write 
        // select distinct f from Focus f left join fetch f.modules where f.id = :id 
        // using Criteria API

        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<FocusEntity> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(FocusEntity.class);
        
        Root<FocusEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(FocusEntity.class);
        root.fetch("modules", JoinType.LEFT);
        criteriaQuery.distict(true);
        criteriaQuery.where(builder.equals(root.get("id"), id));

        TypedQuery<FocusEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
                .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false);
        try {
            FocusEntity focusEntity = query.getSingleResult();
            fetchCourses(focusEntity.getModules());
            return focusEntity;
        } catch (NoResultException ignore) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void fetchCourses(List<ModuleEntity> modules) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(modules)) {
            return;
        }

        // write
        // select distinct m from Module m left join fetch m.courses where m in :modules
        // using Criteria API

        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ModuleEntity> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(ModuleEntity.class);

        Root<ModuleEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(ModuleEntity.class);
        root.fetch("courses", JoinType.LEFT);
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
        criteriaQuery.where(root.in(modules)); // fetch courses only for modules of a focus

        entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
                .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
                .getResultList();
    }
}
```

This way you would have all entities in a Context without `MultipleBagFetchException`.

---

As you can see, general idea is to fetch "main" entity (`Focus`) with its dependent entities (`Module`), and then use those dependent entities and `IN` clause to fetch all of their dependent entities (`Course`). To do so you are free to use any tool/library it suits you (I used Criteria API).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give it a try!